# How to remove Cakephp controller name from URL

Tags: cakephp-2.3

i am working on a cakephp 2.x.. right now i have a function called registration in my userscontroller. after my local site in below url come. how to Remove in my url in the name  " **/Controller::UsersCountroller** ".

http://localhost/ashok_sample_site/users/registration/Controller:UsersController.

cakephp

Comment: Could you provide Router::connect code you are using. Guessing it is in app/Config/routes.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in your config/routes.php

`Router::connect('/Your-Customize-URL/*', array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action'));`

In your case should be

`Router::connect('http://localhost/ashok_sample_site/users/registration', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'registration '));`

Answer (score 0):

Should work with:

```
Router::connect('/users/registration',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'registration')
);
```